Как обрабатывать поддомены?
Имеется сайт site.ru и у него имеются динамические поддомены. Как их правильно обрабатывать на локальном сервере и на продакшене? На продакшене у нас вид будет тип subdomain.site.ru/auth, а на локальном сервере насколько я понимаю, должен быть вид такой: localhost:3000/api/:subdomain/auth.
И да, middleware на обработку поддомена я также написал неверно, т.а не имея поддомена, он будет мне выдавать имя моего домена site. Как правильно написать данный middleware?
Как мне это правильно обработать? Вот простое приложение:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const host = req.headers.host; // Получаем хост из заголовка
    const subdomain = host.split('.')[0]; // Извлекаем поддомен
    req.subdomain = subdomain; // Сохраняем поддомен в объекте запроса
    next();
});

app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Вы находитесь на поддомене: ${req.subdomain}`);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Сервер запущен на порту 3000');
});


Такое подойдет? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain

https://github.com/expressjs/vhost
